# Retaining an existing dataset

Tags: analytics, analytics-cloud

How to retain an existing dataset(contains row1-row5) while uploading today's dataset (contains row6 - row10)? (say, today's dataset does not have data of the existing dataset (i.e. row1-row10))

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Glames. That's a lot of different questions jammed into a single question. This makes it hard to answer, and judge different anwers. I would advise you break this up into separate stackexchange questions, so each current subquestions can be fully answered in it's own dedicated place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is incremental updates. This was released with the Spring + release.

For external data (non Salesforce Data) use: [InsightsExternalData Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_object_externaldata.htm)

For Salesforce data use : [sfdcDigest incremental extraction (pilot)](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_bi_integrate_sfdcdigest_incremental_extract.htm)